# How to use Prime Faces tags

Tags: primefaces

I have basic hello word example of Prime Faces.

I have created dynamic web project on eclipse.

I have downloaded primefaces-3.2.jar and put it to class path(WEBINF/Lib). Then I imported the namespace of Prime Faces to my page. However, It does not work.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>

<p:spinner />  
<p:editor></p:editor>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no error. The page just shows nothing.

Comment: not even at the log files for your application server?

Comment: there's no error even in the catalina.log file or, more generally, in the log file of web server you're deploying onto?

Comment: Do standard jsf tags like h:outputText work?

Comment: i am using Tomcat v7. there is no error in the console of eclipse. i looked at the folders of Tomcat. i could not find any log find. how can i find them?

Comment: how bout wrapping it with <h:form> </h:form> ? the spinner and editor ?

Comment: Yes JSF tags work well. I also wrapped them with <h:form> and <f:view> tags. it still does not work.

Comment: is the jar of primefaces is next to the jars of jsf for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the page extention to xhtml from jsp. It works well. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The Primefaces are used only in .xhtml and Facelets are used in .jsp .Please do remember this.

Please check out this Link

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=62264#p62264